# Event and Cubit Communication

Tags: flutter, state, state-management, flutter-bloc

I am facing a challenge while constructing a logic for one of my blocs. I have a bloc which makes use of my booking service which in turn makes an API call to the server and emit few states based on the response recieved. However this service needs a filter parameter which is dynamic and is a result of a state emitted by my filter cubit. How do i establish a communication between my filter cubit and my bookings event. My pseudo code looks like this.

```
class BookingsBloc{
onGetBookingsEvent(GetBookings event, Emitter<BookingState> emit)
{
final bookingContent=bookingService.getBookings(event.bookingFilter);
}
}

class GetBookingsEvent{
Map<String,dynamic> bookingsFilter;
GetBookings(this.bookingsFilter)
{
//The above booking filter should come from my filter cubit state.
}
}
```

//Filter State looks like this.

```
class FilterState extends Equatable {
bool activeOnly;
dynamic filterByIdentifier;
List<String>? orderTypes;
String? loadPort;
String? dischargePort;
String? customerReferenceNumber;
String? fromDate;
String? toDate;
bool submittedSI;
bool draftSI;

FilterState(
  {this.activeOnly = true,
  this.filterByIdentifier,
  this.orderTypes,
  this.loadPort,
  this.dischargePort,
  this.customerReferenceNumber,
  this.fromDate = "",
  this.toDate = "",
  this.submittedSI = false,
  this.draftSI = false});

FilterState copyWith({
activeOnly,
filterByIdentifier,
orderTypes,
loadPort,
dischargePort,
customerReferenceNumber,
fromDate,
toDate,
submittedSI,
draftSI,
}) {
return FilterState(
    activeOnly: activeOnly ?? this.activeOnly,
    filterByIdentifier: filterByIdentifier ?? this.filterByIdentifier,
    orderTypes: orderTypes ?? this.orderTypes,
    loadPort: loadPort ?? this.loadPort,
    dischargePort: dischargePort ?? this.dischargePort,
    customerReferenceNumber:
        customerReferenceNumber ?? this.customerReferenceNumber,
    fromDate: fromDate ?? this.fromDate,
    toDate: toDate ?? this.toDate,
    submittedSI: this.submittedSI,
    draftSI: this.draftSI);
}

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
  "activeOnly": activeOnly,
  "filterByIdentifier": filterByIdentifier,
  "orderTypes": orderTypes,
  "loadPort": loadPort,
  "dischargePort": dischargePort,
  "customerReferenceNumber": customerReferenceNumber,
  "fromDate": fromDate,
  "toDate": toDate,
  "submittedSI": submittedSI,
  "draftSI": draftSI
};
}
```

How can the correct state be listened inside the bookings event class, or is there a better way to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BlocListener for resolving this task. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=bloclistener
It can listen your state and react to it. In addition, try to divide the task into subtasks and use the single responsibility principle in your architecture.    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design
Note also that it looks strange to simultaneously use Bloc and Cubit. Usually use one of the two.